# Windows Driver for multithread app

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

Developing a Windows driver and providing dll for multithreaded applications to call driver functionalities.

```
pDriverObject -> MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = XXX_Create.
```

How do I handle multiple threads calling CreateFile? How do I handle calls to XXX_create from multiple apps? Similarly other interfaces that I'm providing.

Comment: The question is unclear. Please be more specific.

Comment: You seem to be asking "How do I write a driver?"  That's a very broad question and not suited to SO format.

Comment: OK. The point in case multiple threads call CreateFile, the how should this be handled in my driver function XXX_Create.

Answer (score 2):

You won't have to do anything specific to *create* multiple threads. The windows kernel is multithreaded and will assign a worker thread to handle each IRP and call appropriate function in your driver.

However, you will have to make sure that your functions are thread-safe.

Comment: Hoe do i make my function thread-safe? which kernel function should I use to make it thread-safe?

Comment: @user1666555 This is broad question. Please read up thread-safty in C, API documentation on MSDN etc.